# How can I position a component in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

I used a component to rendered the image in a div and want multiple images like that, in a place marked below but couldn't do it due to absolute positioning how can I fix this issues. Below is my code with css.

```
import React from "react";

const ProductFront = () => {
  return (
    <div className="cont ml-64 mt-60 absolute w-4/5  border border-black ">
      <div classname="products relative w-full bg-black h-auto">
        <div className="card mt-16 float-left h-64 w-1/5 border border-black">
          <img
            classname="w-full h-64"
            src="https://scontent.fktm10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/262512378_628365955279273_4012995638484466373_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_rgb565=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=ioxL_kR8x-wAX9SbEac&_nc_ht=scontent.fktm10-1.fna&oh=30b60b2a763ab6d63259208f282c8d49&oe=61B10257"
          />
          <div classname="product-info mt-4 ml-4">
            <span classname="product-name">abc</span>
            <h3 classname="price">300</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductFront;
```

import React from "react";
import ProductFront from "./ProductFront";

```
const ProductList = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProductFront />
      <ProductFront />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Though I used tailwind css but it will translate as following in css.
css->

```
.cont{
margin-left:16rem;
margin-top:15rem;
border-color:black;
poistion:absolute;
width:80%;
}

.products{
positon:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}


.card{
margin-top:16;
float:left;
heigh:16rem;
width:10%
border-color:black;
```

I am rendering the component ProductList in my App.jsx.

Comment: Sumit, You havent Provided any css styling and 'classname' is not the correct syntax

Comment: I provided the css after the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is check out [flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/), which is made for precisely this sort of thing. You probably want something like [this](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#section-justify-content) using e.g. `justify-content: space-around` applied to the parent `div`.

In terms of your provided CSS, it looks like the `img` parent has `className=card` (actually, you wrote `classname`, with a lowercase `n`, which is not correct! JSX always uses [camelCase](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx)). Therefore, edit `.card` to include `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`, in addition to whatever other properties you want it to have.

If you would like more detail than that, please provide a working, minimal example on e.g. [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io). Here is a [react template](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo0mzz6r2x) you can use as a starting point. Providing an example allows the community to see exactly what you are doing and make finer-grained tweaks to help you achieve what you want. There are a large number of typos in your code, e.g. you say both `poistion` and `positon` in your CSS, neither is which is correct (you're looking for `position`), so it's safe to say that the code you've copied in doesn't work as is. This make it hard to provide concrete help.

That said, I've provided you with the tools to do what you want here. Please read up on flexbox, and then if you still have specific questions that you can articulate, the community will be happy to answer them.

Comment: I edited the css out.

Comment: how can I implement flexbox here.

Answer (score 0):

Your className attribute is incorrect on a couple of the `<div>`'s. You have it classname, it matters is React. https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style